# How can I call a Python function from a form in Django?

Tags: python, django, function, view

I'm trying to call a function from a form in one of my templates to calculate a value in a Django project. The function is in Python. This is the way I'm doing it. I am keeping `myScript.py` in the app folder where `views.py` is.

`template.html`:

```
...
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="nonlBis" name="bisBtn">Submit</button>
...
```

`views.py`:

```
from app.myScript import *
...
def Functions(request):
    if(request.GET.get('nonlBis')):
        print(myScript.myFunction())
```

Comment: do you get error ? always put full error message (full Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: No, I'm not getting any error, the page just reloads, in the url I'm getting the data from my form but nothing in the console

Comment: normally form sends data in POST, not in GET. You may have to use `request.POST` in Python, or `<form method="GET"`...>`  in HTML.

Comment: and you have `name="bisBtn"` so you have check `get("bisBtn")`, not `get("nonlBis")`

Answer (score 0):

I will do it this way.

1. Give your button an 'ID'.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="nonlBis" name="bisBtn" id="btnSoSpecial">Submit</button>
```

2. Bind Js function to that button. Replace 【YOUR API URL HERE】 with your real url that you created in your urls.py.

```
$("#btnSoSpecial").bind('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "【YOUR API URL HERE】", //replace it with your real url
        data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{csrf_token}}',
            nonlBis:$(this).data('value'),// This part might needs some modify 
        },
        async: true,
        success: function (ret) {
            //Do stuffs with returning data
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log('Something went wrong.Deal with it.');
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    })
});
```

3. Link the API url to the function in your views.py,maybe it's like

```
path('api/functionA', views.Functions, name='functionA'),
```